# Spring Security OAuth2 with JWT redirect to login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I created Spring Security application with OAuth2 and JWT. When it is running, I'm getting a login page.
Below I mentioned `pom.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.java.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>AuthorizationWithOauth2nJWT</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AuthorizationWithOauth2nJWT</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Below mentioned the `AuthorizationServerConfig.java` file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private String clientId = "client-id";
    private String clientSecret = "my-secret";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager getauthenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(tokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(getauthenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(tokenEnhancer());
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(clientId)
                .secret(clientSecret)
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(20000)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(20000);

    }

}
```

Here is the ResourceServerConfig.java file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(100)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/**").authenticated();

    }
}
```

Here is the SecurityConfig.java file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/getuser").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Below I mentioned the application.yml file

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: test
      password: test

security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      filter-order: 3
```

I used postman to execute the API. Authorization and request body is define below images.

[image]

[image]

After execute the API, I'm getting below response with 200 status code.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
    <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>
    <form name='f' action='/login' method='POST'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help or workarounds for solve this issue is really appreciate.

Comment: what do you  really want ? Do you want to obtain an access token/ID Token as if you are using an API (ex:- without login page) ?

Comment: @KavinduDodanduwa yes I want Access Token and Refresh Token without login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added UserConfig.java class and add below code.

```
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

     @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth
                    .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("test")
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode("test123"))
                    .roles("USER","ADMIN","MANAGER")
                    .authorities("CAN_READ","CAN_WRITE","CAN_DELETE");
        }
```

In AuthorizationServerConfig.java class, remove public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) method and add below code.

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                .scopes("READ", "WRITE")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "id_token");


    }
```

And I removed below configurations in application.yml file

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: test
      password: test
```

Success response mentioned in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What OP really wants is here is to obtain an access token as if its obtained from an API.

For this, OAuth 2.0 defines two grant types

1. [**Client Credentials Grant**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)
2. **[Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)**

In both occasions, you skip the login screen and invoke token endpoint to obtain an access token. Please read the RFC (links above) to understand when and where you should adopt these grant types.

I am not a Spring expert, hence here I am linking to a tutorial found on net which explains both grants with Spring.

- **[password-grant](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springboot-oauth2-password-grant)**
- **[client-grant](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springboot-oauth2-client-grant)**

Comment: This links are really helpful to me. Thank you

Comment: Still my issue is not solved. I tried my best but I no any happy path

Comment: @LakshithaGihan what do you face now ? A small explanation can make someone who know the $subject help you.

Comment: @ Kavindu Still the same issue. I think my username and password not encode. Because I did all configurations in application.yml file in another project and it's working fine. But it is not a good practice.

Comment: @LakshithaGihan have you checked Postman's encoding support ? For example changing paramters to send as form post or URL encoded ?